# Three.js animation

Tags: three.js, timeline.js

What's the best coding option to utilise ThreeJS as a timeline for a story telling project? I want to use ThreeJS to animate a the story of an actor in a previous production of "Merchant Of Venice". I have stills and video of the actor from the show and I'm going to build a 3D theatre set telling the story of his production with movement around the 3D theatre set displaying stills and video of the production.

I coded with Flash Development (Actionscript 3) for several years. I've also done quite a lot of motion graphics with After Effects. And YES, I DEFINITELY want to use ThreeJS / WebGL tech. I DON'T want to do it with After Effects. I don't want to do it with Flash. I DEFINITELY want to use ThreeJS.

What I'm asking is can someone please point me to an efficient Javascript library which will best utilise ThreeJS as a timeline that tells an animated story from beginning to end? I've seen a few options such as Timeline.js, Greensock Tween engine with ThreeJS; there's an excellent example at Threejs.org deploying Google's "Kuda" library demonstrating a pump building itself. As developers, we all know the old story: "Oh yes, you could try that - but this would have been better.”

Apologies if my question is long-winded and woolly but I want to make the best choices early, not late. I DO want ThreeJS. What’s the best coding option to make ThreeJS a story telling timeline?

Many grateful thanks for all input. Cheers
Keith
KSQ Design

Comment: I think your question is too broad. You cant expect a tutorial here, so maybe you have tried something which you can show?

Comment: I agree, you're right. The question is too broad. I thought so when I posted it. I'll update when I have specific examples to discuss. In the meantime if I may stand by the original question, it's this: What’s the best JS library / coding option to make ThreeJS a story telling timeline? I'm not looking for a free ride. Just thought someone might have already gone down the same road. I will keep experimenting and update. Thanks.

Comment: May you check the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Asking for the "best JS library" is not what stackoverflow is about.

Comment: Hering, I agree. I will post my code and be more specific from here on.

Comment: Hum, I'm just about to make a release of #timeline-jscode, it will fit perfectly with your project. I would want to get your input.

Answer (score -1):

What is usually done is to use the combination of several libraries, in that case, would come https://greensock.com/ excellent for mixing with ThreeJs, he even combination IS USING CSS Animations, it IS ART AND Hay Que Occupy All Resources . 
I'm not very good for English, saludos.